# ls gives me different sort orders during a cron job

Tags: shell-script, cron, ls

I have a cron job that, among other things, does a recursive ls of a directory into a file.  This gets compared to another file that I've created that, supposedly, contains an identical listing of the same directory.  My problem is that, when I generate the version for comparison, I get the files listed in case-insensitive order.  When the cron job runs, its list comes out in case-sensitive order.

How can I get both of these to come out the same way (I don't care which)?  My call to ls is
`/bin/ls -lR --time-style=long-iso *`; as far as I can tell, LC_COLLATE is not set in either setting.

Comment: "as far as I can tell"? Have you simply run both with `LC_ALL=C ls ...`?

Comment: No, but that seems to work nicely -- thanks!  If you re-enter it as an answer, I'll be happy to give you the points.

Comment: In my experience, anything odd that happens in a cron job is due to 1) cron's very limited environment, or 2) unescaped percent signs in the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting problems can be avoided by explicitly forcing applications to use a certain sort order. You can check the current locale by running `locale` instead of the program in question and compare the output of different call situations.

The sort order can be forced by setting `LC_COLLATE` / `LC_ALL` within the command line:

```
LC_COLLATE=C ls ...
LC_ALL=C     ls ...
```