# What's with `-` in filename affecting sorting order depending on platform?

Tags: bash, sort, cygwin, busybox

I just checked if contents of directory on my cygwin/Win7 development system, and test embedded platform running Linux+Busybox are the same. Simple, `cat * | md5sum` on both (RXVT/Bash on Cygwin, serial console on Busybox/Bash), compare. And... mismatch. So I went manually file-by-file, doing `md5sum *` and...

Cygwin:

```
  c69a7926998066fcb79aad3e2fc0c33f *blankpack
  5866f29a5bc74f741bcc1074c883abaa *cleanup.sh
  d4923d7df2540e279664b0633784f1c4 *clean-www.sh
  c44ab61b62af040ee55a3e4ddc271299 *d
```

Linux:

```
  c69a7926998066fcb79aad3e2fc0c33f *blankpack
  d4923d7df2540e279664b0633784f1c4 *clean-www.sh
  5866f29a5bc74f741bcc1074c883abaa *cleanup.sh
  c44ab61b62af040ee55a3e4ddc271299 *d
```

Somehow the two cleanup scripts switched places. The same happens with `ls`, `echo *` etc.

Is this some bug? Some dependency on the underlying OS? Which of the two orders is the "correct one"(if any)?

Comment: Have you saved the file in different systems? Can it be a CRLF/LFCR discrepancy?

Comment: @vfbsilva: As md5sum proves, the contents are identical, even though the file on cygwin functions on NTFS (and on busybox, on yaffs2).

Comment: Do the `locale` match on the two systems?

Comment: @choroba excelent comment. SF. look here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78084/ls-gives-me-different-sort-orders-during-a-cron-job

Comment: @choroba: Cygwin has pretty much all LC_ variables (except LC_ALL, empty) as "pl_PL.UTF-8". Busybox has no locale.

Comment: Oh. After `export LANG=` the order switched. Must be it. (...still, what insanity possessed the developers to switch that order in the locale?)

Comment: @SF: The sort order is defined by the language. If you don't like it, switch the corresponding LC variable to `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `locale` setting on the machines. The sort order depends on the regional settings.